# Behat CSS selectors work in chrome, not in firefox

Tags: css, selenium, firefox, behat

I've just started to work with Behat and Selenium. I'm doing test automation for websites and I have the problem that some CSS selectors work in Chrome but are not found in Firefox.

For example, I have this in Behat:

Then I press ".topmember-resultList .resultListItem .resultListInteractions div:nth-child(1)"

The 'Ipress' method searches for an element with the selector and clicks it.

As I said it works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox the tests fail because the element wasn't found. It seems to happen only when I use nth-child. But afaik, Firefox (48.0) should support that as well.

Comment: Have you checked manually in both browsers? it is possible that the elements are not displayed the same. Please provide the complete stack-trace if possible.

Comment: Theoretically there's nothing wrong with using a lot of selectors like this in behat, but you also might consider a simpler test. For example: 'I should see x' followed by 'Then I press x', forgoing all the selectors. Just use the text/content you're expecting to see in the link/button.

Comment: Strangely enough it seems I have solved it by turning nth-child into nth-of-type. That works the same way, and also in Firefox. Although the elements are the same in both browsers. No idea why but fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a big problem all of us find when trying to recycle code from chrome tests to firefox tests.

You can try the following:

Create an abstract context where you can put all the methods/steps that have no conflict in your tests.
Then You can create two contexts that extends from your abstract class, one for chrome and one for firefox. This way you can use the same method for both browsers but with different code in each one. (You will need to differentiate the browser context definition in your behat.yml file)
In the chrome context, you can put your original method using your working cssSelector.
In the Firefox one, create the same method but use the CssSelector that works with firefox. Or use Xpath selector that it's a good solution too in firefox.

Hope it helps.